# want to run a function without background service which task to check location is enable?

Tags: android, service, gps, location, iteration

I want to execute a function with some specific time interval. It should be executed when GPS-location is disable and when user exit the app. I want to run that function to check whether GPS-Location is enable or not, if it found enable then I need to close the execution of function again and again at some specific interval of time.

Is there any way to execute such function without background services ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it by using `TimerTask`

Comment: @MD: Not reliably. That goes away once the process is terminated, which can be at any point once the app's UI is no longer in the foreground.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ya you're right. then `Services` is only option here.

Comment: @MD: i use BroadcastReceiver which is perfect for my Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to run that function to check whether GPS-Location is enable or not

You are welcome to set up a manifest-registered `<receiver>` to listen for [`PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION) and/or [`MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#MODE_CHANGED_ACTION) broadcasts. You can conditionally enable and disable that receiver, via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`, so you only listen for those broadcats when you deem it to be relevant.

This avoids your proposed polling solution, saving the user's battery.

> Is there any way to execute such function without background services ?

You can find out about the provider changes via the broadcasts mentioned above, and that on its own does not require a service.

However, you also have to take into account the work that you intend to do when that broadcast is received. If this will do any I/O (disk I/O, network I/O, etc.), you need to delegate that to a `Service`, probably an `IntentService`, to get that work off of the main application thread, yet still be likely to have the work complete.

And, if you insist that doing this on a timed basis, the only somewhat reliable solutions for that (`AlarmManager`, `JobScheduler`, etc.) require services to do the work, though not services running all of the time.

Comment: Thanks, you solve my issue, i use BroadcastReceiver which eliminate extra function-calling and service. so its perfect solution for my question.

Thanks again.